# Django refuses to parse javascript variable when creating qr code

Tags: django, django-templates

I have been trying different ways to try to make django read the javascript variable but nothing has been working. Either it prints the variable as a string or gives me an error. I am trying to create a qr-code, I need to enter the qr-code information which is stored in a js variable.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

const id = document.getElementById('id-input-product');
    function loadPreviewProduct() {
      value = '"' + id.value + '"';
      document.getElementById('qr-code').innerHTML = `{% qr_from_text ${value} size="t" image_format="png" error_correction="L" %}`;   
    }

   
  </script>
  <div id="qr-code">
  </div>
```

Comment: You can't use a javascript variable in django template tags.

Comment: How do I access the values inside of the form without posting the form then?

Comment: you can make an ajax call or predefine it with Django.